# How to pass an Twig expression as a parameter to a template, and then execute it with template's context?

Tags: symfony, templates, twig

I define a template which built select dropdown inputs for my forms:

```
<p id="{{key | ucfirst}}">
    <span>{{label}} : </span>
    <select required disabled>
        {% for d in data %}
            <option value="{{attribute(d, optionValue)}}" {{(attribute(d, optionValue) == selectedValue)?'selected'}}>{{attribute(d, optionIntitule)}}</option>
        {% endfor %}
    </select>
    <span><em>{{initialValue | default("")}}</em></span>
</p>
```

Then I just need to include it, and passing it some data:

```
{% include 'selectForm.twig' with {'label': 'Manager'
                                            , 'key': context.manager.id
                                            , 'initialValue': projet.manager.username
                                            , 'data': users
                                            , 'keyValue': 'id'
                                            , 'keyIntitule': 'username'
                                            , 'selectedValue': projet.manager.id) } 
%}
```

**It works fine, but I want to do more.** For instance I would like to show a value more usefull for end user into option's label: `<option>Username (email)</option>` instead of `<option>Username</option>`

So I think I can't use anymore the `attribute` function.
I thought I could pass [an expression](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/templates.html#string-interpolation) to my template like following:

```
{% include 'selectForm.twig' with {..., 'keyIntitule': "#{d.username (d.email)}"} %}
```

But the expression is evaluated with immediate context, not template's one. So it doesn't work.

[I also tried with `template_from_string`](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/functions/template_from_string.html) but I don't suceed in (I never used this function before...)

Is there a way to pass an expression to another template, and make it evaluate the expression with it's own context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution with Twig's `template_from_string` function:

```
{% include 'selectForm.twig' with {..., 'keyIntitule': template_from_string("{{d.username}} ({{d.email}})")} %}
```

And then I use `keyIntitule` variable as a template:

```
<option value="{{attribute(d, optionValue)}}">{% include(keyIntitule) %}</option>
```

Works also with:

```
<option value="{{attribute(d, optionValue)}}">{{ include(keyIntitule) }}</option>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to block the immediate context you can use [include function](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/functions/include.html) instead of [include tag](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/include.html). Then you can disable context this way (example taken from the documentation) :

```
{# only the foo variable will be accessible #}
{{ include('template.html', {foo: 'bar'}, with_context = false) }}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you working with objects you could set `keyIntitule` to `uniqueName` and in the user entity define new method:

```
public function getUniqueName()
{
    return sprintf('%s (%s)', $this->getUsername(), $this->getEmail());
}
```

Twig will call corresponding getter method. In this case `uniqueName` transforms to `getUniqueName()`